# How to prevent Xaml class from resetting variables

Tags: c#, xaml

When the page is reloaded either by clicking on the Home -> Page3 or the Page3 button the `cartTitleListDisplay` list gets reset, is there a way to prevent this?

List Creation:

```
List<string> cartTitleListDisplay = new List<string>();
```

The program works by getting the data via sending the variable data to the Page3 navigation button on the MainPage and collecting it on Page3, Page3 has a safety to prevent if null information was added and then displays the information on Page3

```
protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    List<string> cart1temp = e.Parameter as List<string>;

    if (cart1temp != null)
    {
    cartTitleListDisplay.AddRange(cart1temp);
    }

    if (cartTitleListDisplay != null)
    {
        cartTitle1.Text = cartTitleListDisplay[0];
    }
    try
    {
        cartTitle1.Text = cartTitleListDisplay[0];
        cartPrice1.Text = cartTitleListDisplay[0];
    }
}
```